# Search words similarity in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say in `PostgreSQL` database I have table called `questions`. As you can see in that table I have records which similar for human but not similar for database. Is it possible to take all records similar to 90 percent of the list of questions?

```
| QUESTION_ID | QUESTION_TEXT                                    |
|-------------|--------------------------------------------------|
| 1           | What is your favorite movie, cartoon and series? |
| 2           | What is your favorite movie cartoon and series   |
| 3           | what is your favorite Movie, Cartoon and Series  |
| 4           | Do you like apple?                               |
| 5           | do you like Apple                                |
```

Right now I use next code which return only 2 record:

```
select
    *
from
    questions
where
    question_text in (
        'What is your favorite movie, cartoon and series?',
        'Do you like apple?'
    )
```

As I know PostgreSQL has `pg_trgm` module which help search similarity by `word_similarity` function. How to add this function to my request correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You'd do it like this:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE INDEX ON questions USING gin (question_text gin_trgm_ops).
```

Then you can efficiently search like this:

```
SELECT question_id
FROM questions
WHERE question_text % 'What is your favorite movie, cartoon and series?';
```

`%` is the “similarity operator”, and the threshold when things are considered similar can be set with the parameter `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold`.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html) for more.

Comment: Thank you very much! As I said before I need to select all the records that will be 90 percent similar to 2 sentences. As I understand I need set value of percent in `pg_trgm.similarity_threshold` parameter, right? Also in your example your compare only with one sentence. How to make compare with several sentences?

Comment: Define what you mean by "90% similar". To search for several strings, write a `UNION` of several single queries.

Comment: For example, if `word_similarity` function refurn `0.9` we can assume that the match is 90 percent. Is it possible to get the desired result without `UNION`?

Comment: I don't think it would work without `UNION`. If `word_similarity` is your definition of similarity, then you should have no problem.